# Using JAXB to separate atributes from one class to multiple elements in XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm still at a design phase, so I don't have any code snippets at the moment.

## Context

I'm writing an application to compose relatively complex XML, with 3 main elements and about 25 parameters (mostly attributes and some values). There is quite a lot of custom types, so XJC generates about 15 classes (most of them are however strings or numbers with some added constraints).
Edit: There is one root element, which contains these 3 elements, that I'm talking about.

The purpose of it is to allow the user to generate a large variety of different variants allowed by the schema. So I basically need to create a swing form and eventually create xml based on the inputted data.

It doesn't seems practical to attempt to somehow map 25 different fields in a form to a tree-like structure of objects (especially since many of the attributes are optional, so some of the object shouldn't even exist until the user inputs something).

So the best solution seems to be to save the data from the swing form to one bean (or a few) and then create some representation which JAXB will then marshal.

## Question

Is there a way to convince JAXB to take that one bean and directly create 3 elements with attributes and values all taken from that one class?

Edit: After some discussion, different way of asking would be: Is there a way to flatten the object model, that xjc generated for me?

Comment: Are these 3 main elements a part of a single holder XML? If so, yes JAXB can do the trick. Otherwise, if you want to take a bean and create multiple XML files, then it's gonna be tricky and more importantly incorrect.

Comment: Yes, these 3 elements are wrapped by root element. I hope there is a way, since putting it all together by hand would be quite unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you're already using XJC and your final object contains a root element with 3 main children elements (which in-turn have a complex structure). There's no convincing needed from JAXB, just find out the top level class generated in the XJC output and start using it directly in your resource method, marshalling & un-marshalling should happen out of the box.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Yes, I can create the top level class and marshall it, but I have to put in it 3 different object and I have to put various other objects into those and so on... But I need to get those data from swing form and I can't really use this complicated structure as data object for this form. That is why I would like to flatten it and have everything in one object ideally.

Comment: This should have been taken care of automatically if your XSD schema has the intended structure defined properly (root -> child 1 + child 2 + child 3). XJC will automatically create a top level class with references to children classes as it's fields.

Comment: Yes, but I have to fill all those object with data, which I'm given in the form. While if it was only one class, I could use it as a bean and map it directly to textfield in my swing form.

Comment: I see your concern, model structure shouldn't be influenced by such constraints. You could use a binding framework for swing that will help you directly bind your form element to the correct property of your class.

Comment: Exactly, but this is lot more difficult to do, if the content of a field in a from actually belongs in an object in an object in the root object (the object representing the root element), that is why I would like to put all the attributes of these 3 element in the same class (basically flatten the object structure).

Comment: It's not difficult if it's done in the right way. Think about a case where-in you'd want to add more / remove sections from your form. Have a well-defined model will ensure only front-end changes (mapping) are required and your back-end can remain the same, since your abstractions are quite strong.

Comment: I have some doubts about this, for example in order to map a text field to some object, which represents an attribute of one of the elements, the object already needs to exist, but if it is optional, than it can't exist unless somebody inputs something in the corresponding text field.

Comment: A binding framework would take care of that. If the text-field is not filled and  that maps to the only attribute in an element, it won't create that element. OTOH, in the reverse case, it wouldn't fill your text-field with any data. Since it's parent is NULL. Keep in mind, the presence of text-field itself shouldn't be dependent on whether the attribute is present or not, keep your UI design and model design separate and use a binding framework to do the mappings as you wish.

Comment: I will read up on some binding frameworks than, although I was hoping for an easier way.